# XSLT - test multiple sibling nodes and return true if any sibling matches the test

Tags: xml, xslt

TIA for your help. I'm still learning XSLT so please feel free to tell me what I have already come up with should be done a different way.

I am trying to process the following XML and insert `<newtag>` with a true or false value based on a few simple conditions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FILE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <HEADER>
        <LINE>
            <LINENO>1</LINENO>
            <DOLLARS>100</DOLLARS>
        </LINE>
        <LINE>
            <LINENO>2</LINENO>
            <DOLLARS>100</DOLLARS>
                <REASON>
                    <CODE>1</CODE>
                </REASON>
        </LINE>
        <LINE>
            <LINENO>3</LINENO>
            <DOLLARS>0</DOLLARS>
                <REASON>
                    <CODE>99</CODE>
                </REASON>
        </LINE>
        <LINE>
            <LINENO>4</LINENO>
            <DOLLARS>0</DOLLARS>
                <REASON>
                    <CODE>99</CODE>
                    <CODE>1</CODE>
                </REASON>
        </LINE>
    </HEADER>
</FILE>
```

If DOLLARS > 0 insert `<newtag>false</newtag>`

If DOLLARS = 0 and CODE is in a list of values insert `<newtag>true</newtag>`

Otherwise insert `<newtag>false</newtag>`

My problem is the case where there are two (or more) CODE tags as siblings of the DOLLARS tag.

This is the XSLT I have so far.

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 

<xsl:output 
    method="xml" 
    version="1.0" 
    encoding="UTF-8" 
    indent="yes" 
    omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- global template to copy everything that doesn't match the other templates -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

 <!-- Find the DOLLARS tag for every line -->
 <xsl:template match="DOLLARS">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="number(../DOLLARS) > 0">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <newtag>false</newtag>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="contains('-1-2-3-4-5-6-', concat('-', ../CODE, '-'))">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <newtag>true</newtag>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <newtag>false</newtag>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I know that the problem is that the contains test is only finding/testing the first CODE, but I don't know how to get it to test both CODE tags and give me a true if either CODE is a match.

David

Comment: "*My problem is the case where there are two (or more) CODE tags as children of the DOLLARS tag.*" In your example, the DOLLARS element has no children. The CODE elements are children of REASON, which is a **sibling** of DOLLARS (it helps to indent the code properly in order to see this). Now, are you sure you want to insert the `<newtag>` element as child of DOLLARS? It will create *mixed content*, making it more difficult to process at the next stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good job. I like to see users new to XSLT use something than `xsl:for-each` :-)

Looks like you only need to add the test for `DOLLARS = 0` and move the `contains()` into a predicate.

You could also simplify the `xsl:choose` by removing the test for `DOLLARS > 0` since the result is the same as the `xsl:otherwise`. You could move the `xsl:copy-of` out of the `xsl:choose` as well.

Example...

```
<xsl:template match="DOLLARS">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test=".=0 and ../REASON/CODE[contains('-1-2-3-4-5-6-', concat('-', ., '-'))]">
            <newtag>true</newtag>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <newtag>false</newtag>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Another option is to split it into two separate templates instead of using the `xsl:choose`...

```
<xsl:template match="LINE[REASON/CODE[contains('-1-2-3-4-5-6-', concat('-', ., '-'))]]/DOLLARS[.=0]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <newtag>true</newtag>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="DOLLARS">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <newtag>false</newtag>        
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Question edited based on Michael's comment. Thank you.

Comment: @DLoysen - Michael's result and the result using either of the options in my answer are basically the same. The only difference is the location of `newtag`, but it's still at the same level in the hierarchy and wouldn't create mixed content.

Answer (score 1):

> If DOLLARS > 0 insert `<newtag>false</newtag>`
>
> If DOLLARS = 0 and CODE is in a list of values insert
>   ``true
>
> Otherwise insert `<newtag>false</newtag>`

I believe this could be rewritten as:
1. Insert a `<newtag>` element.
2. If DOLLARS = 0 and CODE is in a list of values. then let the value of `<newtag>` be true; otherwise false.

Consider the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="valid-codes">
    <code>1</code>
    <code>2</code>
    <code>3</code>
    <code>4</code>
    <code>5</code>
    <code>6</code>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="LINE">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <newtag>
            <xsl:value-of select="DOLLARS=0 and REASON/CODE=exsl:node-set($valid-codes)/code"/>
        </newtag>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FILE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <HEADER>
      <LINE>
         <LINENO>1</LINENO>
         <DOLLARS>100</DOLLARS>
         <newtag>false</newtag>
      </LINE>
      <LINE>
         <LINENO>2</LINENO>
         <DOLLARS>100</DOLLARS>
         <REASON>
            <CODE>1</CODE>
         </REASON>
         <newtag>false</newtag>
      </LINE>
      <LINE>
         <LINENO>3</LINENO>
         <DOLLARS>0</DOLLARS>
         <REASON>
            <CODE>99</CODE>
         </REASON>
         <newtag>false</newtag>
      </LINE>
      <LINE>
         <LINENO>4</LINENO>
         <DOLLARS>0</DOLLARS>
         <REASON>
            <CODE>99</CODE>
            <CODE>1</CODE>
         </REASON>
         <newtag>true</newtag>
      </LINE>
   </HEADER>
</FILE>
```

Comment: Thank you. I liked the idea of putting the codes into a variable. My actual transform needs to check the codes in 4 different XML tags and not having to repeat the contains list 4 times was appealing even if it was just for readability. Unfortunately when I tested this when the value of the select was true nothing was returned. I suspect that exsl is not available in the application I am putting this into.

Comment: @DLoysen Are you sure about that? I am not aware of any XSLT 1.0 processor that does not support the EXSLT node-set() extension function. Still, if that's true, you could place the codes in another XML document or even in the stylesheet itself, under a different namespace. Let me know if you need more help with this.

Comment: There is very little about XSLT that I am sure of. The XML and XSLT I posted for this question are sanitized versions of what I'm really working with, so it is entirely possible I messed something up. I'll probably try your solution again when I have time, but who knows when that will happen. Thanks for the help.